# Why did heroku build fail with gradle and spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, heroku, gradle, plugins

I'm trying to set basic workspace for Spring boot and gradle.
Everything works perfectly in local and in travis, but in heroku build fails. I don't think the problem is in the actual code, but in the configuration.

Here is my project in [github.](http://github.com/rovaniemi/gramise)

```
build.gradle

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven'
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.3.RELEASE'
}

group = 'org.karlin'
version = '0.1.0'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

bootRepackage {
    mainClass = 'gramise.Gramise'
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile("com.google.code.gson:gson")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    compile("org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp2")
    compile("com.h2database:h2")
    testCompile(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-
    starter-test', version:'1.5.3.RELEASE') {
        exclude(module: 'commons-logging')
    }
    testCompile group: 'com.jayway.jsonpath', name: 'json-path', version:'2.2.0'
}

task stage(dependsOn: ['build', 'clean'])
build.mustRunAfter clean
```

There is heroku build log

```
-----> Gradle app detected
-----> Installing OpenJDK 1.8... done
-----> Installing Gradle Wrapper...
       WARNING: Your application does not have it's own gradlew file.
-----> Building Gradle app...
-----> executing ./gradlew build
       Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/1.5.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-1.5.3.RELEASE.pom
       Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-tools/1.5.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-tools-1.5.3.RELEASE.pom
       Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-loader-tools/1.5.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-loader-tools-1.5.3.RELEASE.pom
       Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/io/spring/gradle/dependency-management-plugin/1.0.2.RELEASE/dependency-management-plugin-1.0.2.RELEASE.pom
       Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/spring-core/4.3.8.RELEASE/spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.pom
       Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/1.5.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar
       Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-loader-tools/1.5.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-loader-tools-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar
       Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/io/spring/gradle/dependency-management-plugin/1.0.2.RELEASE/dependency-management-plugin-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar
       Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/spring-core/4.3.8.RELEASE/spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar

       FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

       * What went wrong:
       org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaPlugin
       > org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPlugin

       * Try:
       Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

       BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: "Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output." - did you do this?

Comment: Yes, there is full log with --stacktrace option 
https://gist.github.com/rovaniemi/86300470cf11abb30ff92f0fe84f31d1

Comment: I'm not looking at it.  You should.

Comment: Yep, I know that heroku think the plugin is broken, but I'm still not understand why it work in travis and local. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `gradlew` into Git.

```
WARNING: Your application does not have it's own gradlew file.
```

Because you are not doing this, Heroku is using a very old version of Gradle.

Comment: Okay, I will do that too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else is encountering this problem, this fixed it

I added buildscript in build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.3.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}"
    }
}
```

Now everything is working, thanks for help.